# Float and jQuery UI button

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui, internet-explorer-7, jquery-ui-button

I used jQuery UI buttons in a project, and they have been working fine.

But, in IE7, the icon doesn't float as it should. I realise IE doesn't have rounded corners support yet, but that is OK.

### *<strike>Good browsers</strike>Some browsers* render it fine

[image: good example]

### IE <strike>sucks</strike> version 7 does not:

[image: bad example]

I start with a button in the HTML

```
<button type="submit"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-mail-closed"></span>Send</button>
```

I then loop through the buttons, using this little bit of jQuery on each

```
$('#content button').each(function() {                
    var icon = $(this).find('span.ui-icon');
    var primaryIcon = icon.attr('class').replace(/ui-icon\s?/, '');
    icon.remove();
    $(this).button({ icons: {primary: primaryIcon }, label: $(this).text() });
});
```

I was just calling `button()` on them, but I decided to do this to make sure I was using the library the way it was designed.

I had some CSS on the icon too

```
button span.ui-icon {
    display: inline;
    float: left;
    margin-right: 0.1em;
}
```

The page from above is [also available](http://bit.ly/bBoHvZ). (shortened to void HTTP referrer, I hope).

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks very much!

### Update

I tried making the icon as an inline block element, as per [Meder's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3853171/help-with-float-and-jquery-ui-button/3853528#3853528).

```
button span.ui-icon {
    display: inline;
    float: left;
    margin-right: 0.1em;
    margin-top: -1px;
    /* get rid of margin for inline element */
    #margin: auto; 
    /* this should revert the element to inline as per declaration above */
    #float: none; 
    /* hasLayout = true */ 
    #zoom: 1;
}
```

This, however, has the unusual affect of blanking the button elements!

[image: IE7 with display: inline-block on icon]

Whatever shall I do?

Comment: go Bananas, and Recipe of the Week: is `Prawn Risotto with Peas`

Comment: @Rakesh I don't understand your comment.

Answer (score 1):

Anyway, when you float an element it becomes a block box. Display:inline is useless.
And you should always set a width on floated items.

Comment: `display: inline` is useful for avoiding the double margin bug in IE6. Why should I always set a width, when IE7 is the only browser having an issue?

Answer (score 1):

You need to explicitly define a width for horizontal floats or the [float drops](http://work.arounds.org/issue/81/floats-drop-next-line-ie/). The alternative is using [inline-block](http://work.arounds.org/issue/18/using-inline-block-ie7-and-ie6/).

If that doesn't work let me know.

Comment: Thanks Meder. I might use `inline-block`. I'll try in the morning, I'm going to have a break now.

Comment: Hey Meder, I tried giving the icon `display: inline` (or its equivalent) for IE7 and the buttons went blank! See my edit on OP - give me a pointer in the right direction and you will have an accepted answer sir!

Answer (score 0):

```
<button type="submit"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-mail-closed"></span><span style="float:left;">Send</span></button>
```

Answer (score 0):

your rendered html,

```
<button type="submit" class="ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-button-text-icon-primary" role="button" aria-disabled="false">
    <span class="ui-button-icon-primary ui-icon ui-icon-mail-closed"></span>
    <span class="ui-button-text">Send</span>
</button>
```

have you tried css,

```
button span.ui-button-text {
    display: inline;
    float: left;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tried that, and then I tried it again just then with IE Developer Tools, and it didn't work :(

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
button span.ui-icon {
    display: inline;
    float: left;
    margin-right: 2px;
}
button{width:75px;}
```

IE need a width for the button I think.

[Here's my jsfiddle try](http://jsfiddle.net/3SgjR/8/)

Comment: Can someone explain the downvote? It works on IE7 http://jsfiddle.net/3SgjR/8/embedded/result/